# How to implement jsplumb community in a project with angular 16

Tags: angular, jsplumb

I need to implement the jsplum library with angular 16, the detail is that the examples I get use angular 5 or less, and therefore the methods are deprecated and are not compatible with angular 16.

On the official website the help is almost non-existent, and in the forums they use up to Angular 5. It seems that it only works up to this version of Angular

Comment: There seems to be some documentation here - https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/toolkit/6.x/lib/angular-integration

Comment: The documentation is only for the paid version, that is why the version is specified in the title, jsplumb community